# Ошибка в Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Ничего не понимаю в php (сам по js), и при создании сайта на самом сайте поверх всего выдаёт такой текст ошибки:

```
Warning: sprintf(): Too few arguments in <ТУТ ПУТЬ К PHP ФАЙЛУ> on line253
```

Строки кода:

```
251  $item = !empty($matches)

252  ? preg_replace('/(<a.*?)([\'"])>/i', '$1$2 itemprop=$2item$2>', $item)

253  : sprintf('<a href="' . esc_url($link_item) . '" itemprop="item">%s</a>', $item);
```

(цифрами 251, 252, 253 обозначены строки).

Кто знает, что делать?

Comment: Предупрездение о том что в регулярное выражение попадает что-то не то что ожидидают.. и регулярка не отрабатывает правильным образом.

Comment: Ну это-то понятно, это буквально говорится (to few arguments). Я пробовал что-то прочесть в коде и смотреть уроки по php на ютубе. Понял лишь то, что я ничего не понял и то, что надо лучше разбираться в чужом коде.

Comment: Верни путь к файлу (во всяком случае от корня ВП). А функцию нужно писать полностью

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Количество аргументов, которое требуется функции `sprintf` для работы -- кол-во спецификаторов + 1 (самый первый аргумент -- строка со спецификаторами). Если выбрасывается ошибка, что аргументов меньше, чем нужно, то это говорит о том, что спецификаторов в строке больше, чем аргументов, переданных после этой строки. Я вижу в строке только один спецификатор -- `%s`. Вероятнее всего в `esc_url($link_item)` содержатся еще спецификаторы, для которых не хватает аргументов. А возникает это из-за того, что `esc_url` может подменять символы на комбинации символов, похожие на спецификаторы `sprintf` ([пример](https://wp-kama.ru/function/esc_url#example_35050)). Отсюда скорее всего и возникает ваша ошибка.

Я вообще не уверен в необходимости использовать здесь `sprintf`. Ваша строка не содержит преобразований строки `$item`, а значит можно заменить функцию обычной конкатенацией строк:

```
$item = !empty($matches)

? preg_replace('/(<a.*?)([\'"])>/i', '$1$2 itemprop=$2item$2>', $item) 

: '<a href="' . esc_url($link_item) . '" itemprop="item">'. $item .'</a>';
```

Comment: Старик, очень сильно благодарю тебя. Ты решил мою проблему, над которой я бился дна 3-4. Очень сильно благодарен